# WPF set checkbox content above the checkbox

Tags: wpf, checkbox, styles

I have a checkbox where I would like the text content of it to be placed above the checkbox control. I have seen an article in which the text is placed to the left of the textbox, [as seen here](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/19141/WPF-Checkbox-Text-On-Left-Side), but I would like to know if there is a way to set a style to get the content shown either above or below the checkbox?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Just modify the template from the link and set the property `DockPanel.Dock` for the BulletChrome and the ContentPresenter

Comment: Article linked has been deleted

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the same technique as the article you linked.  Just use `DockPanel.Dock="Bottom"` instead of `"Right"` for the `BulletChrome`.

You may want to also set  `VerticalAlignment="Top"` and `HorizontalAlignment="Center"` for the `Content`, as well.